# Select the first row in a join of two tables in one statement

Tags: sql, db2

I need to select only the first row from a query that joins tables A and B. On table B exist multiple records with same name. There are not identifiers in any of the two tables. I cannot change the scheme either because I do not own the DB.

```
TABLE A
NAME

TABLE B
NAME
DATA1
DATA2

Select Distinct A.NAME,B.DATA1,B.DATA2 
From A 
Inner Join B on A.NAME = B.NAME
```

This gives me

```
NAME       DATA1    DATA2
sameName   1        2
sameName   1        3
otherName  5        7
otherName  8        9
```

but I need to retrieve only one row per name

```
NAME       DATA1    DATA2
sameName   1        2
otherName  5        7
```

I was able to do this by adding the result into a temp table with a identity column and then select the minimum id per name.

The problem here is that I require to do this in one single statement.

Answer (score 10):

This will work:

```
with temp as (
    select A.NAME, B.DATA1, B.DATA2, 
        row_number() over (partition by A.NAME order by A.NAME) as rownum
    from TABLEA A inner join TABLEB B
    on A.NAME = B.NAME
)
select NAME, DATA1, DATA2 from temp where rownum = 1
```

If you want to select the least value of data1 and within it data2, then use this variation:

```
with temp as (
    select A.NAME, B.DATA1, B.DATA2, 
        row_number() over (partition by A.NAME order by B.DATA1, B.DATA2) as rownum
    from TABLEA A inner join TABLEB B
    on A.NAME = B.NAME
)
select NAME, DATA1, DATA2 from temp where rownum = 1
```

Both the queries will give one row per name.

Comment: It would be better to do the partition by `B.name`, so you can use an index (if one exists).  You wouldn't even have to bother reporting `A.name` (because of the comparison).

Comment: Great solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

Using a GROUP BY may get you part way there, but beware.  If you do something like this:

```
Select A.NAME, min(B.DATA1), min(B.DATA2) 
From A Inner Join B on A.NAME = B.NAME 
Group by A.NAME;
```

You will get the result you are looking for:

```
  NAME      DATA1   DATA2
  sameName   1        2    
  otherName  5        7
```

But only because of the data you are testing with. If you change the data, so that instead of:

```
otherName  8        9
```

you had:

```
otherName  8        4
```

It would return:

```
  NAME      DATA1   DATA2
  sameName   1        2    
  otherName  5        4
```

Note that otherName does not return DATA1 and DATA2 from the same record!

Update: A self-join with a comparison on one of the data values may help you, such as:

```
SELECT a.*, b.* FROM a,b 
   LEFT JOIN b b2 ON b.name = b2.name AND b.data2 < b2.data2 
   WHERE a.name = b.name AND b2.data2 IS NOT NULL;
```

However, this will only work if the values in DATA2 are unique per NAME.

Comment: There's a small typo on the last statement. It should be "IS NOT NULL" instead of "IN NOT NULL".

Comment: +1 you are a savior. Your edited self join works even with SQL CE where other solutions for this question do not due to SQL CE's limitations.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will solve your problem or not, but you could try using the GROUP BY clause and group by one of the name columns.

[DB2 Group by tutorial](http://www.geocities.com/srcsinc/database/db2_tutorials/sql_tutorials/DB2_SQL_TUTORIAL_5.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you can add to a temp table and then query from that, you can do it in one go.

```
WITH T AS (temp table select), RN AS (select min row-numbers from T) SELECT T.NAME, T.DATA1, T.DATA2 FROM T INNER JOIN RN on T.row_number = RN.row_number
```

There are many other ways to write this, but that's how I've been doing similar things.

Answer (score 0):

Try to dedupe B like this

```
SELECT  A.NAME, bb.DATA1, bb.DATA2 
FROM    A 
JOIN    B bb
ON      A.NAME = B.NAME
WHERE   NOT EXISTS (SELECT  *
                    FROM    B
                    WHERE   NAME = bb.NAME
                            AND (DATA1 > bb.DATA1
                                OR DATA1 = bb.DATA1 AND DATA2 > bb.DATA2))
```

Add more OR clauses if more DATAx columns exist.

If A contains duplicates too, simply use DISTINCT as in the OP.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  A.NAME, bb.DATA1, bb.DATA2 
From A Inner Join B on A.NAME = B.NAME
WHERE B.DATA1 = (SELECT MIN(DATA1) FROM B WHERE NAME = A.NAME)
```

This will give your desired result, providing B.DATA1 values are *unique* within the set relating to table A.

If they're not unique, the only other way I know is using CROSS APPLY in MSSQL 2005 and above.

Answer (score 0):

The tag of this question indicates that it would be a solution for DB2, but this is very similar to MS-SQL server, if so try these solutions:

Using CROSS, it will be possible to display what exists only in both tables

```
select A.*, B.DATA1, B.DATA2
from A
cross apply (select top 1 * from B where B.name = A.name) B
```

But it is possible to change to OUTER to display what exists in A without the obligation to exist in B

```
select A.*, B.DATA1, B.DATA2
from A
OUTER apply (select top 1 * from B where B.name = A.name) B
```

In the structure of the apply statement, it would also be possible to include an ORDER statement, since there is no indication of the order of exits in table B

Answer (score 0):

You can use row number to get one row for each name, try something like below

```
Select name,data1,data2 from 
(Select A.NAME,B.DATA1,B.DATA2,row_number() over(partitioj by a.name order by a.name) rn
From A 
Inner Join B on A.NAME = B.NAME) where rn=1
```