# How to LEFT JOIN in DB2 iseries with first row?

Tags: sql, db2, iseries-navigator

I have need a query that JOIN a TABLE with A first row of other table value based:

```
 SELECT * FROM TABLEA A LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT * from TABLEB
       WHERE FIELD1 <> '3' and FIELD2 = 'D' AND A.CODE=CODE
      FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY
     ) B
 on a.FIELDA = b.FIELDA
 and A.FIELDB = B.FIELDB
```

but DB2 return ERROR because can't use **A.CODE**

How can solve this?

Comment: You are referring to tablea (aliased as A) in your derived table, but you don't have it in the from clause.  I think you need to move it to your join clause.

Comment: Can you give me a code?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Select the first row in a join of two tables in one statement](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/774769/select-the-first-row-in-a-join-of-two-tables-in-one-statement)

Answer (score 12):

You need to use the *nested table expression*:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLEA A LEFT JOIN
  LATERAL (SELECT * from TABLEB
     WHERE FIELD1 <> '3' and FIELD2 = 'D' AND A.CODE=CODE
     FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY
  ) B
on a.FIELDA = b.FIELDA
and A.FIELDB = B.FIELDB
```

Comment: I might of down voted I don't remember.  Down votes cost reputation so don't worry about it.  Where exists will easily out perform a fetch first 1 row only statement.

Comment: To be fair the `where exists` is not the same or equivalent of the query in the question as it only returns columns from TABLEA and not TABLEB.

Answer (score 1):

**This is a highly optimized statement.**
Your not getting any data from tableb and your going for first row so you just need exists clause.

```
select a.* from tablea a 
where exists (select * from tableb b 
    where a.fielda = b.fielda 
    and a.fieldb = b.fieldb 
    and b.code = a.code 
    and b.field2 = 'd' and b.field1 <> '3')
```

Comment: However, since the code said `SELECT *`, we don't know what columns Daniele might be using from TableB

Comment: @WarrentT That's true.  I thought of that and almost changed my answer.  But select first one rows only without an order by clause you wouldn't know what rows were actually returned only that a few fields would match.  Without knowing more intimate details I went with where exists because I often do these give me Students with at least one course type of queries.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the OLAP function `row_number()` to rank the records according to somefield(s) within a (fielda,fieldb,code) group.  Somefield might be a transaction id, or sequence, for example.  The order by clause is optional there, but without it, you might be randomly picking which record is the first in the group.

```
 WITH B AS
 (SELECT *,
         row_number() over (partition by fielda,fieldb,code
                            order     by somefield
                           ) as pick 
    from TABLEB
    WHERE FIELD1 <> '3'
      and FIELD2 = 'D'
 )
 SELECT * 
   FROM TABLEA A LEFT JOIN B

       on a.FIELDA = b.FIELDA
      and A.FIELDB = B.FIELDB
      and A.CODE   = B.CODE
   where pick=1
```